# Transit visa for Vietnam through their evisa website

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, vietnam, vietjet-air

I'll be travelling back to India from Busan, Korea via Hanoi, Vietnam. In that case, I think, I'll require a Vietnamese transit visa. My question is how to apply for one. Now, I now that there is https://evisa.xuatnhapcanh.gov.vn/trang-chu-ttdt website through which I can apply. But, as far as I know we can apply for a single entry tourist visa through this and there is no provision for transit travellers. Say, if I apply for their tourist visa, the authorities will ask me to provide hotel accommodation which obviously I don't have because my layover is of 9 hours. I fear that in that case my application might be rejected.

Comment: https://www.myvietnamvisa.com/vietnam-transit-visa.html says that you don't need a transit visa as long as you're not going to clear immigration for any reason. Does that apply to you?

Comment: Yes, i need to clear immigration as i need to collect baggage.

Answer (score 1):

Select regular options as you browse through the website. Except for a field where you have you give purpose of visit. Change it to "transit" from "tourism". Then, verify Passport info and make Payment. It won't ask you for hotel stay info or any other information once you change the purpose of visit.